# C# WebRequest does not wait for GetResponse()

Tags: c#, .net

I seem to be having an issue with HttpWebRequest while attempting to download data from a service that uses OAUTH. I first create an HttpWebRequest, then put the OAUTH information in the Authorization header. However, the header gets sent as soon as GetRequestStream() is called (verified by Wireshark). The service expects that the header and the body are part of the same request, not separate requests. The data should not be sent until GetResponse() is called. Please let me know if you have any idea how to ensure that all the data is sent at the same time. Thanks.

```
private HttpWebRequest GetWebRequest(string requestURI_, string token_, string        tokenSecret_, int contentLength_)
{
    Uri requestURI = new Uri(requestURI_);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestURI);

    request.ProtocolVersion = new Version("1.1");
    request.Expect = null;                              //Turn off the "Expect" header
    request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    request.SendChunked = false;
    request.ServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;

    string authHeader = "";
    GetOAUTHHeader(out authHeader, requestURI, token_, tokenSecret_);

    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
    request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    request.UserAgent = "DotNet3.5";
    request.Accept = "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = contentLength_;

    return request;

}

private string GetWebResponse()
{   
    string requestBody = "This is the request body";            
    HttpWebRequest request = GetWebRequest(requestURI_, accessToken_,    accessTokenSecret_, requestBody.Length);

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();                 //For some reason, the headers are sent here
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
requestWriter.Write(requestBody);
    requestWriter.Close();
    requestStream.Close();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();                   //The body of the request is sent here
    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string responseInfo = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    responseReader.Close();
    response.Close();

        return responseInfo;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the response status, description and stuff? I didn't really buy what you said. Also...try first without setting the propertes of request except the authorization. Leave everything default. Also use using instead of .Close

Comment: I tried with all properties set to default except the authorization header, and I am still seeing this issue. The response status returns OK and the description is "OK". The request appears to have an extra header "Expect: 100-continue." Stepping through with the debugger, the header is sent when GetRequestStream() is called.